# Add external mac launcher to install4j

Tags: macos, install4j

I want to include an external mac launcher in my install4j project. The problem is, that the mac launcher is a folder and install4j only accepts files as external launcher. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External launchers for macOS media files are not supported as of install4j 8.0.

Comment: I have upgraded my install4j to version 8.0.2 , but I still can't add the external mac launcher. I'm trying to add the launcher just like the external windows launcher. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe you misread my answer, I said that they are **not** supported.